# how to build post method in C# to save data from front end as an Object?

Tags: c#, reactjs, json, .net, post

Object is below mentioned.

```
[answers: {{queId:2, ansId:1, score:3}, {queId:3, ansId:2, score:2}, {queId:4, ansId:3, score:1}}]
```

Above mentioned object can be get using axios.

I need to save these data in database table. Table is consisted with erId, queId, ansId & score. (erId sets to auto increment.) Already created a model and DBContext for this table. How to write POST method in controller class?

Comment: C# is a completely different language from C.  Tags edited.

Comment: I am sorry but your question is absolutely unclear, why do you need to use javascript to get data if you can get data using a controller action?

Comment: JavaScript used to get the above object. Now i need to pass this to the backend POST method to add object data into database table.

Comment: Why don use the backend acion to get the above object and save it to DB?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be better and consistent to create a dto object rather than just using an object?

You can create a Dto class as following:

```cs
public class ResponseDto
{
   public int erId { get; set; } 
   public int queId { get; set; } 
   public int ansId { get; set; }
   public double score { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller file you can use it as following:

```cs
[HttpPost()]
public async Task<ActionResult> MyEndpoint([FromBody] List<ResponseDto> body)
{
  // write your logic here 
  var response = await SomeBusinessLogicMethod(body);
  return Ok(response);
}
```

Remember that C# is strongly typed language, try avoiding using "object" too much, only use "object" when it is really needed.